# Showing that $3$ is a generator of the group $(\mathbb{Z}/31\mathbb{Z})^{\times}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

> Show that $3$ is a generator of the group $(\mathbb{Z}/31\mathbb{Z})^{\times}$.

I have done the following:

The order of the group is $30=2 \cdot 3 \cdot 5$.

$3$ is a generator if $3^2, 3^3, 3^5 \neq 1$.

Indeed, $3^2=9, 3^3=27, 3^5=26$.

Is this correct??

Comment: You must also check $3^6\neq 1$, $3^{10}\neq 1$, $3^{15}\neq 1$.

Answer (score 2):

No, but it is enough to show that none of $3^{30/2}$, $3^{30/3}$, and $3^{30/5}$ is equal to the identity.

Comment: In my notes there is the following proposition: 
Let $G$ a finite cyclic group of order $n=q_1^{a_1} \cdots q_t^{a_t}$ and $g\in G$, Then $g^{\frac{n}{q_j}}\neq 1$ for $1 \leq j\leq t$ if and only if $ord(g)=n$. 
$$$$ 
So, can we not use this??

Comment: @MaryStar:  Yes, we can, but you didn't.  The $q_j$ are $2,3,5$.  So the $\frac{n}{q_j}$ in the theorem that you quote are $15, 10,6$ exactly as in the answer above.

Answer (score 2):

To show that 3 generated $(\mathbb{Z}/31\mathbb{Z})^*$ you must show that the order of 3 in $(\mathbb{Z}/31\mathbb{Z})^*$ is 30. Now if suppose $p$ is the order of 3 then it follows that $p$ divides 30. Therefore $p$ can be either 2,3,5,6,10,15 or 30. Since $3^i$ for $i=2,3,5,6,10,15$ is not 1, it follows that the order of 3 is 30.

Comment: In my notes there is the following proposition: 
Let $G$ a finite cyclic group of order $n=q_1^{a_1} \cdots q_t^{a_t}$ and $g\in G$, Then $g^{\frac{n}{q_j}}\neq 1$ for $1 \leq j\leq t$ if and only if $ord(g)=n$. 
$$$$ 
So, can we not use this??

Comment: That is in fact correct. Because if $p_1, p_2, p_3$ are divisors of $o(G)$ then if $a^{p_1}=1$ then $a^{p_1p_2}$ is also 1.

Comment: So, is what I have done in my initial post correct?

Comment: You need not check for $3^3, 3^5,3^2$ but you have to verify that the elements $3^{15}, 3^{6} , 3^{10}$ are not identity.

Answer (score 0):

$$d_1(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}^{\times}) = \{x: \textrm{gcd}(x,n)=1\}$$

If you can't simply use that fact and want to show it recall,

$$ \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}^{\times} = \{y: (y,n) = 1, y<n\}$$

$\\$

Note that $3^{30} = 1 \Rightarrow \textrm{ord}(3) \mid 30 \Rightarrow \textrm{ord} = 2,3,5,6,10,15,$ or $30$

Comment: In my notes there is the following proposition: 
Let $G$ a finite cyclic group of order $n=q_1^{a_1} \cdots q_t^{a_t}$ and $g\in G$, Then $g^{\frac{n}{q_j}}\neq 1$ for $1 \leq j\leq t$ if and only if $ord(g)=n$. 
$$$$ 
So, can we not use this??

Comment: So, is what I have done in my initial post correct?